# How to solve access to Log analytics working around PIM in Power Query

Tags: azure, powerquery, azure-log-analytics

I have a Power bi report that accesses Log analytics on Azure. It worked well as long as my PIM is active. But once it is deactivated my report data refresh stops working.

I have set up my data connection through web api

[image]

I sign in using  Organization account. This works fine as long my account is active through PIM. I need a way to solve this. please help

[image]

The power query code
let
strRangeStart = DateTime.ToText(RangeStart,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),
strRangeEnd = DateTime.ToText(RangeEnd,[Format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Culture="en-US"]),

```
 Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/xxxxxx-1554-499b-a4ca-dcde7f3a4a90/query", 
[Query=[#"query"="
SynapseIntegrationPipelineRuns 
| where Level == '''Error'''

| where TimeGenerated >= datetime(" & strRangeStart &") 
| where TimeGenerated < datetime("& strRangeEnd &") 
| project PipelineName, RunId, Start, End, OperationName, Status

",#"x-ms-app"="OmsAnalyticsPBI",#"prefer"="ai.response-thinning=true"],Timeout=#duration(0,0,4,0)])),
TypeMap = #table(
{ "AnalyticsTypes", "Type" }, 
{ 
{ "string",   Text.Type },
{ "int",      Int32.Type },
{ "long",     Int64.Type },
{ "real",     Double.Type },
{ "timespan", Duration.Type },
{ "datetime", DateTimeZone.Type },
{ "bool",     Logical.Type },
{ "guid",     Text.Type },
{ "dynamic",  Text.Type }
}),
DataTable = Source[tables]{0},
Columns = Table.FromRecords(DataTable[columns]),
ColumnsWithType = Table.Join(Columns, {"type"}, TypeMap , {"AnalyticsTypes"}),
Rows = Table.FromRows(DataTable[rows], Columns[name]), 
Table = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Rows, Table.ToList(ColumnsWithType, (c) => { c{0}, c{3}})),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table,{{"End", type datetime}, {"Start", type datetime}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [End] >= RangeStart and [End] < RangeEnd)
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

Comment: what's the issue? You want the powerquery to work when your account is NOT active through PIM?

Comment: Maybe it is as easy as using another account that is not a  PIM. But I just need some instruction the best way to do that. Is it to create a service principal and/or setting up a azure ad group. The service principal I think must have some access to Log Analytics workspace or something. I need some clarification here